# UWP ContentControl not showing space in its content

Tags: uwp, whitespace, behavior

I am trying to add content control in a stackpanel as like in below code snippet

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ContentControl Content="Test 1"/>
        <ContentControl Content=" ### "/>
        <ContentControl Content="Test 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the above code,the space after the content (" ### "), in the second content control is not shown in the result.

Please refer to the screenshot below

[image: ScreenShot]

Note in the above image, there is no space after ###.

Could anyone please let me know, whether this is the behavior or an issue with ContentControl?

My exact scenario is to add this panel as ItemsPanel of ItemsControl. Please refer to below code

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Test 1"/>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text=" ### "/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test 2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Regards,
Shobika.

Comment: `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ContentControl Content="Test 1"/>
        <ContentControl Content=" ###"/>
        <ContentControl Content=" Test 2"/>
    </StackPanel>` space after words which has no meaning

Comment: @ketan I have added the space before and after the content **" ### "**. But in the result, space before the content (Test 1 ###) is shown and space after the content is not shown (###Test2).

Comment: i tried above posted code it will add the space try above code.

Comment: @ketan Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried this already. But my question is why can't we add space after the words. Because, in WPF, the same code (which I have posted at first) works fine. That is, it add space after the word. But in UWP, why can't we achieve the same behavior with same code?

Answer (score 0):

XAML will fold some of the spaces, which is why the trailing spaces cannot be displayed. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/whitespace-processing-in-xaml) explains this in detail.

For your code, I suggest that you can use the `TextBlock` to replace the `ContentControl`, we need to use the `Run` in `TextBlock`:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Test 1"/>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="&#160;###&#160;"/>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Test 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

`&#160;` is an escape character for XML, representing a space.

---

**Update**

Please note that `&#160;` is an XML escape character, please do not use it in C# code. In Code-behind, use

```cs
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " #"+(char)160 });
```

If you choose to create an `ItemsControl` item in code-behind, please modify the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`.

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have gone through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/whitespace-processing-in-xaml#white-space-normalization) which you have shared and also this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-and-whitespace#whitespace-processing). And I have a question that how the trailing spaces is displayed in WPF but not in UWP ?

Comment: Hello, there is currently no documentation for this issue. It is worth mentioning that XAML in UWP is inherits from WPF, but with some changes, deleting trailing spaces may also be one of them.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it fails for me. My exact scenario is to add this stackpanel as ItemsPanel of ItemsControl. I have updated code in the query. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Yes, I have tried replacing `&#160`. It works when adding textblock in simple stackpanel. However It is fails in my scenario of adding it in ItemsControl. Following the exact code which I have tried.                                                          `var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "&#160;#&#160;" });
            itemsControl.Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Test 1" });
            itemsControl.Items.Add(textBlock);
            itemsControl.Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Test 2" });`